# Need a simple sample on how to store/load my custom class for iOS development

Tags: objective-c, ios, class

I have the following objective-c class:

```
@interface LatLongData {
    NSMutableString *_lat;
    NSMutableString *_long;
    NSMutableString *_altitude;
}

-(LatLongData*) initWithLat:(NSMutableString*) latitude Long:(NSMutableString*) longitude Altitude:(NSMutableString*) altitude;

@end
```

How can I store/load an instance of that object? I have tried working with code like this:

```
LatLongData *data = [[LatLongData alloc] initWithLat:_lat Long:_long Altitude:_altitude];

// Save
NSData *theData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:data];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:theData forKey:LatLongDataKey];

//...

// Load
NSData *loadedData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dataForKey:LatLongDataKey];
LatLongData *ldata = (LatLongData *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:theData];
```

But I have no luck with that...
I know I should read everything about Core Data. I will but at this point it would be very nice to get my little sample to work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [NSCoding protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) with your class.
`@interface LatLongData <NSCoding>`

Here are a few protocol methods:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        lat = [[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"lat"] copy];
        long = [[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"long"] copy];
        alt = [[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"alt"] copy];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeObject:lat forKey:@"lat"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:long forKey:@"long"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:alt forKey:@"alt"];
}
```

**P.S.** You need to replace `theData` at your last line with `loadedData`